# Recordset is not updateable

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that contains another query, as shown in the picture (they are separated by the solid black line). They do not contain any criteria/conditions. When I run the query for the bottom one, I am unable to modify the recordset. Could someone explain why? And if it's possible to work around that? Thanks!

[image: My two queries]

Answer (score 1):

In Access queries that are created using multiple outer joins are not updateable. The easiest way around this is write your first query to a temporary table first, then use the temporary table with your second query.

Comment: Do you know the conceptual reason why it doesn't update? Where does Access get confused about the user's intended flow of information?

For a temporary table, do I need to use VBA to write the information to the table? Thanks!

Comment: Here is an ok reference on this: http://www.fmsinc.com/Microsoftaccess/query/non-updateable/index.html one reason behind the logic of non-updatable query has to do with access referencing the correct id's to make the change.